# Configure Multiple Network Cards for ubuntu server

Tags: server, networking

I have installed ubuntu server 12.04, I intend this to be a headless web cache server. I used the text-based setup wizard to configure the first NIC.

I have eth0 set static, now i would like to set eth1 and eth2 to use dhcp from a different domain. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: The circumstances of my situation has changed. I will repost a new question with all the relevant information in another post.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces`, as it probobly will explain how you want your server set up.

I would do this, if I understand your problem right:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The network interfaces that you want to start
auto eth0 eth1 eth2
# Your static interface
iface eth0 inet static
      address ...
      netmask ...
      ...
# Your other interfacese that is set up through dhcp
iface eth1 inet dhcp
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

Comment: The circumstances of my situation has changed. I will repost a new question with all the relevant information in another post. Thank you for the response, Anders.